# How to borrow a parameter from another function in CoffeeScript?

Tags: function, coffeescript

I am working with some code. I have a character file that looks like this:

```
character = (name,level,health,species,admin,donor,weapon) ->
    alert "Name = "+name
    alert "Level = "+level
    alert "Species = "+species
    if admin = (true)
        alert "He is an Admin"

    if donor = (true)
        alert "Thanks"

    alert "What a shiny "+weapon
```

I also have a attack file like this:

```
attack = (name,weapon,target,damage) ->
    alert name
    alert weapon
    alert target
    alert damage
```

I want to have the `health` subtracted by the `damage`. I don't know how to borrow a parameter though. How would I do it?

Comment: `if admin = (true)` is the same as writing `if admin = true` and does not compare anything.

Comment: Character should be a class, then you can make an instance of a character and 'attack' can manipulate its members. [Here is a guide on classes in coffeescript](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html)... But it assumes knowledge of the idea of a "class" which it sounds like you may not yet have. Read about object-oriented programming, it may take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably closer to what your idea might look like in coffeescript

```
class Character
    constructor: (@name, @level, @health, @species, @admin, @donor, @weapon) ->
        console.log "Name = " + @name
        console.log "Level = " + @level
        console.log "Species = " + @species
        if @admin is yes
                console.log "#{@name} is an Admin"

        if @donor is yes
                console.log "Thank you for donating #{@name}"

        console.log "What a shiny " + @weapon

    attackedBy: (attacker, target, damage) =>
        @health -= damage;
        console.log "#{attacker.name} did #{damage} points of damage when attacking #{@name}'s' #{target}"
        console.log "#{@name} now has #{@health} health"

bob = new Character 'Bob', 1, 100, 'Dwarf', no, yes, 'Pole staff'
frank = new Character 'Frank', 1, 50, 'Human', yes, no, 'Short sword'

bob.attackedBy frank, 'Head', 40
```